# Remove all or certain special Character from beginning of the String

Tags: java, regex

I am running through a scenario where i have to create table through jdbc statement and i am receiving the table name as method argument. Oracle database is used and Oracle has naming rule like table name should not start with any of these following character `$#_`. I want to replace  all those special character only from the beginning but not from in_between or at the end. For example:

`#_PHYSICIANS` → `PHYSICIANS`

`##_#_PHYSICIANS` → `PHYSICIANS`

`##_#_PHYSICIANS_#_NAME` → `PHYSICIANS_#_NAME`

What Regular expression shall I use to replace these characters from the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

Whatever characters you want to strip from the beginning, you can put them in the character set and use this regex,

```
^[#_]+
```

and replace it with empty string.

Here `^` marks the start of string and `[#_]+` means one or more characters from character set.

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("#_PHYSICIANS","##_#_PHYSICIANS","##_#PHYSICIANS_#_NAME");
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.replaceAll("^[#_]+", "")));
```

Prints,

```
#_PHYSICIANS --> PHYSICIANS
##_#_PHYSICIANS --> PHYSICIANS
##_#PHYSICIANS_#_NAME --> PHYSICIANS_#_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.If its working for you

```
^($|#|_)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/wg9TEe/1

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replaceFirst("^[#_$]+", "");
```

`^` means from the beginning, `[...]` lists the chars, `...+` one or more.

Answer (score 1):

This removes the part before any character.

```
 String text = "#_PHYSICIANS_#";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
 if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.start());
   String result = text.substring(m.start(), text.length());
   System.out.println(result);
 }
```